# Why is input from a numericUpDown object not considered constant?

Tags: winforms, user-interface, c++-cli

I am making a basic GUI password creator that creates a random sequence of letters, numbers, and symbols in C++ (it's a Windows Forms Application).  I am using a numericUpDown object to retrieve the user input for the length of the password being created.  I am trying to define a char array using that number as the length, but I get an error that says "expected constant expression."  I tried defining it as a constant variable but even that doesn't work.  Is there any workaround?

The below code is part of what is executed when the "Randomize" button is pressed (the button that prompts the password to be created and then displayed.

```
const int length = System::Convert::ToInt16(numericUpDown1->Value);
```

And then later in the program:

```
char p[length];
```

Comment: Post the code. A description is fine, but without any code it makes it extremely difficult to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot declare arrays with a variable size in c++ (same goes for c++/cli).

It sounds like you want to generate a random array of characters and convert it to a `System::String` (`System::String` is immutable, so you need the array to manipulate the data).  For this, you'll want to use a `array<wchar_t>` instead.

```
array<wchar_t>^ data = gcnew array<wchar_t>(System::Convert::ToInt32(numericUpDown1->Value));
// fill each character in data with a random character.
System::String^ password = gcnew System::String(data);
```

Edit: in case you're wondering why a `wchar_t` instead of `char`: in c++/cli, `wchar_t` is analogous to `System::Char`, which is the character type used by .NET.  `char` would be analogous to `System::SByte` (a signed byte).